# Get database data from different url pages - what is the best technology?

Tags: node.js

I want to create a mobile app  that call various urls and get for each url a different response based on SQL Server data.

I try to use Nodejs for this job but when I get the data, I cannot retrieve a single response for that page.

Someone suggested to use Socketweb.io instead of routers... what is the best option for your experience?

This is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var dbResp;
const sql = require("msnodesqlv8");
var buf = '';
var router = express.Router();

const connectionString = <my connection string>;


router.get('/page1', function (req, res) {

    var query = "SELECT query 1";
    sql.query(connectionString, query, (err, rows) => {
        try {
            grows = rows;
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                buf += "get the data...";
            }
        }
        catch {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    });

    res.send(buf);
});

router.get('/page2', function (req, res) {
    var query = "SELECT query 2";

    sql.query(connectionString, query, (err, rows) => {
        try {
            grows = rows;
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                buf += "get the data...";
            }
        }
        catch {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    });

    res.send(buf);
});

app.use('/page1', router);
app.use('/page2', router);

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
});
```

Comment: can you post example of the result, and what do you want to receive?

Comment: i get the results joined and not one at time,e.g. after two calls one for page1 and the second for the page2 i get query 1 and query2 joined but i want one response for each call not the entire response buffered. it's difficult to explain. I want to receive the query 1 when i call page1 and the query 2 when i call page 2...

Comment: Show me ur calls to api. And why r u using buf globally. Declare it individually in each of ur routes.

Comment: You're getting both because your variable "buf" is declared globaly

Comment: yes! i solve in that manner.

Comment: How i can "reset" the cached data" every time a get a new request? if i call two times the same route the web page show two set of data quequed.

Comment: By setting buf = "" at the start of your route definition